# Same sound different meaning

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What's the difference in using **practise** instead of **practice** and **advise** instead of **advice**?

I always get confused when using them in sentences or essays..

Answer (score 3):

Your post’s title is misleading. The meaning of “practice” and “practise” is the same; it’s just the spelling that’s different. “Practice” is the American spelling; “practise” is the British/Commonwealth spelling.
**EDIT**: According to Smock, “practise” is a verb in the UK but “practice” is a noun. In the US we use “practice” as both a verb and noun. These two words sound the same.

“Advice” and “advise” do **not** sound the same. The former is a noun and is pronounced with a voiceless consonant at the end (“s” sound). The latter is a verb and is pronounced with a voiced consonant at the end (“z” sound).

Comment: Actually in the UK we use Practise and Practice to mean two different things. Practise is to rehearse (to repeat something) and practice refers to the activity itself. So you might practise repeatedly at the practice of basket-weaving

Comment: @Smock that is good to know- I wasn’t sure if “practise” could be a noun. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In British English, practise and advise are verbs while practice and advice are nouns.

In American English,  practice and advice function as both nouns and verbs.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, I didn't catch it earlier, but "advice" in AE is only a noun.